# how to delete documents in batch in firestore using python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a collection named XYZ in my firestore. And there are 500 documents with different fields in it.
I have to delete multiple documents using a where clause from the collection.

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('XXXX')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.Client()

batch = db.batch()

doc_ref = db.collection('collection_name').where(u'month', '==', 07).get()

for doc in doc_ref:
      batch.delete(doc)

batch.commit()
```

I tried this but ending up with an error

```
AttributeError: AttributeError: 'DocumentSnapshot' object has no attribute '_document_path'
```

Looking for help!

Comment: You have to actually execute the query with `get()` and get document references from the results in order to pass them to `batch.delete()`.  You can't pass a Query object.

Comment: No, It didn't work.

Comment: If you want help with that, you should show what you tried, and explain what didn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to show your updated code.  Don't leave it in a comment.  Use the edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Edited. You can check the complete snippet that I've tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a DocumentSnapshot object to `batch.delete()`, which is not allowed.  You must pass a DocumentReference object instead, which can be found in a property of a DocumentSnapshot.

```
  batch.delete(doc.reference)
```